# Change employer and address during pending I-485

Tags: visa, greencard, employment, usa, interview

I've left my previous company during my pending I-485 (which is pending 150 days now, filed on Oct. 18, 2017). I'm in Texas now, but will possibly go to California for my new job.

Do I need to inform USCIS of my employer change right now? In my interview, just in case they asked me about my employer, can't I just say I changed my employer?

Comment: Assuming "I-148" means I-485, if your application relies on an I-140 petition and has been pending for less than 180 days I believe the job offered in the I-140 needs to be available on the day the I-485 is approved. If that job is no longer available this is a material fact that you cannot conceal. You really should be asking a lawyer about this.

Comment: Yes I-485, sorry. Yeah, I've been told the job needs to be of similar description.